# set Webview2 header or cookie

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, webview2

I want to set customized header for all requests that Webview2 makes. Please help. Basically I want to load website in webview itself so it is needed that I receive my header on all requests.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace O2C
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = "O2C-Web";
            webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
            webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;
        }

        private void WebView_NavigationStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.RequestHeaders.SetHeader("X-Authorization", "My Auth");
        }
    }
}
```

```
e.RequestHeaders.SetHeader("X-Authorization", "My Auth");
```

I have found the correct event which will work for the requirement but I don't know how to call that event from xaml file or from .cs file.
Following docs say thaat this event will work for the requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.webresourcerequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.864.35

BUT how to hook that event and from where I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Solved it after looking at many places.

If you want the `WebResourceRequested` Event then you must register the `Filter` that will intercept all requests for all resources. Then and then it will work or called.

I am posting whole code here:

```
private void webView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      //Following line is MUST if you want to use WebResourceRequested Event
      webView.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All);
      webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = "MY-AGENT";
      webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
      webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;
      webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
}

private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
{
      e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("X-Authorization", "My Auth");
}
```

Thanks all for support and ideas. Hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

That event WebResourceRequested is on the CoreWebView2 class and you can find your CoreWebView2 as a property on the WebView2 class after the WebView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event fires.

```
        private void webView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsSuccess)
            {
                webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = "O2C-Web";
                webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
                webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;

                webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
            }
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("X-Authorization", "My Auth");
        }
```

Comment: This is not working. There are build errors. I tried this one earlier as well.